# JavaScript - Changing the value of object literals

Tags: javascript

guys!

Basically I want to replace the object literal "title" value of all objects within arr2 with each of the elements within arr1.

```
const arr1 = ['first', 'second', 'third']

const arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'hello'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'world'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: ' '
  }
]
```

For the end result to be this:

```
const final = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'first'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'second'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'third'
  }
]
```

I really don't understand how I could do such a thing, I am totally stranded at this stage.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like as follows:

```
arr2.forEach((x,i)=>{x.title=arr1[i]})
```

x : is element

i : is index

Example:

```js
var arr1 = ['first', 'second', 'third']

var arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'hello'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'world'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: ' '
  }
]

arr2.forEach((x,i)=>{x.title=arr1[i]})

console.log(arr2)
```

if you don't want to modify existing object you can use `map` method

```
arr2.map((x,i)=>{
    return {id:x.id,title:arr1[i]}
})
```

Example:

```js
var arr1 = ['first', 'second', 'third']

var arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'hello'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'world'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: ' '
  }
]

var result = arr2.map((x,i)=>{
    return {id:x.id,title:arr1[i]}
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone your original object (to avoid mutation) and then iterates with a for loop replacing every object inside the array:

```js
const arr1 = ['first', 'second', 'third']

const arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'hello'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'world'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: ' '
  }
]

let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));

for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
  result[i].title = arr1[i]
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why are you doing  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));` What is the use of this

Comment: that is for cloning your original object, to avoid mutation, you get an identical object with a new reference in memory: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-a-grip-on-reference-vs-value-in-javascript-cba3f86da223/#:~:text=Objects%20in%20JavaScript%20are%20passed,allocated%20space%20in%20the%20memory.

Comment: if you want to do that thing then use `map`

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr2.map((v, k) =>{
  v.title = arr1[k]
});
```

You set the title of each item with the string in the `arr1` which is at the same index.